# Boolean input doesnt work on ngif in a child html

Tags: angular

sorry for my bad english, not my main language.

I got a problem, i have a boolean var in a father component to switch language. I have 2 ngifs in all my component to switch language if var is true or false.

app component:

```
public euskera: boolean;


  constructor(){
    this.euskera=false;
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

  setEuskera(){
    this.euskera=true;
  }

  setCastellano(){
    this.euskera=false;
```

app component html:

```
<div *ngIf="euskera">
  <header id="header">
    <img id="logo" src="../assets/img/logoSoinuka.png">
      <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
  
          <li [routerLink]="['/inicio']"><a>hasiera</a></li>
          <li [routerLink]="['/sobre-nosotros']"><a>nor gara?</a></li>
          <li [routerLink]="['/proximos-eventos']"><a>hurrengo ekitaldiak</a></li>
          <li [routerLink]="['/contacto']"><a>kontaktua</a></li>
          <li (mouseenter)="mostrarLenguajes()" (mouseleave)="esconderLenguajes()"><a>Hizkuntza:<span>[</span></a></li>
        </ul>
  
      </nav>
  
  
  </header>

  <div id="language" (mouseenter)="mostrarLenguajes()" (mouseleave)="esconderLenguajes()">
    <ul>
  
      <li(click)="setCastellano()"><a>Gaztelania</a></li>
      <li (click)="setEuskera()"><a>Euskara</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</div>


<div *ngIf="!euskerafalse">
  <header id="header">
    <img id="logo" src="../assets/img/logoSoinuka.png">
      <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
  
          <li [routerLink]="['/inicio']"><a>Inicio</a></li>
          <li [routerLink]="['/sobre-nosotros']"><a>¿Quienes somos?</a></li>
          <li [routerLink]="['/proximos-eventos']"><a>Proximos eventos</a></li>
          <li [routerLink]="['/contacto']"><a>Contacto</a></li>
          <li (mouseenter)="mostrarLenguajes()" (mouseleave)="esconderLenguajes()"><a>Lenguaje:<span>[</span></a></li>
        </ul>
  
      </nav>
  
  
  </header>

  <div id="language" (mouseenter)="mostrarLenguajes()" (mouseleave)="esconderLenguajes()">
    <ul>
  
      <li(click)="setCastellano()"><a>Castellano</a></li>
      <li(click)="setEuskera()"><a>Euskera</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</div>


<div class="son">
    <app-home [euskera]="euskera"></app-home>
  </div>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  </div>
</body>
```

Home component (child)

```
  @Input() euskera:boolean=false;
```

Home component html (child)

```
<div *ngIf="euskera">
  euskera language 
</div>

<div *ngIf="!euskera">
Espanol language 
</div>
```

If I use console log the value of the variable changes from True to false and from false to True but the ngif only shows the text false (loaded by Default) when changing the value of the variable from the parent it is not interpreted from the child since the IF does not work for me

What can i do? Help me pls, im stucked at this point. Thanks

Comment: Is this a typo? <div *ngIf="!euskerafalse">

Comment: Oh sorry its a error when im editting code since the web. The correct code in my pc is <div *ngIf="!euskera">

Comment: Okay no probs. Another strange thing is the additional <body> Element.. you should already have a body in index.html. Besides that, what you have should work..?

Comment: @MikeOne I tried delete body but nothing happened. I dont know how can i fix that...

Comment: Can i send u a youtube link with a video of my problem???

Comment: There is a typo in app component html:  `*ngIf="!euskerafalse"`

Comment: @EmmBee No bro, i check it before and its only an error of pasting code in stackoverflow :(  in my pc i have: <div *ngIf="!euskera">

Comment: It should work. If you want help, provide a link to a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy) example